# How I get jwt token from cognito (without user & password) by login via corporate ID - C# 4.5 (using aws-sdk?)

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, saml

I define a cognito service (of aws) that connect to my idp service by saml protocol (with MD).
In my cognito service I define a callback_url to my localhost project (in C# version 4.5).
I use with UI of aws to login. After I login by "Sign in with your corporate ID" (not by username and password) I get successfully the code in my url from cognito service.

For exmple: https://my-app.com/login?code=xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx

So my question is how can i get jwt token from this code (and clientId, userPoolId) by using aws-sdk (on webapi C# 4.5) - is this possible ? I made a search and found only on js and not on C#?

tnx